# CMake and make consecutive runs with different flags yields same output

Tags: makefile, cmake

Consider the following simplified case:

```sh
cmake ... -DMY_MACRO_USED_IN_CXX_CODE=1
make my_target
echo $(md5 my_target)
cmake ... -DMY_MACRO_USED_IN_CXX_CODE=2
make my_target
echo $(md5 my_target)
```

I use the macro to selectively use code snippets in my c++ project.
During multiple runs of this shell script, sometimes the md5 of `my_target` doesn't change! This happens even if I insert `sleep 1s` after each call to `cmake`. I wonder what is happening here? How do I prevent this? Other than sleep for some randomly long periods?

minimal example:

```sh
# files
main.cc
test.sh
CMakeLists.txt
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0)
project(minimal-cmake-flags)
if (NOT DEFINED MY_MACRO OR "${MY_MACRO}" STREQUAL "")
  set(MY_MACRO 2000)
endif()
add_executable(main main.cc)
target_compile_definitions(main PUBLIC
  MY_MACRO=${MY_MACRO})
```

```sh
#! /bin/bash
function f() {
  cmake . -DMY_MACRO=$1 &> /dev/null
  make main &> /dev/null
  echo $(md5 main)
  ./main
  rm main
}
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
  f $i
done
```

```cc
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef MY_MACRO
#define MY_MACRO (1)
#endif
int main() {
  cout << MY_MACRO << endl;
}
```

Run `bash test.sh` on my machine and it prints:

```
MD5 (main) = e701db90ef8119715a918c97b56e919a
1
MD5 (main) = e701db90ef8119715a918c97b56e919a
1
MD5 (main) = 962a6a241bb4b39c0a99371ddd422eb4
3
MD5 (main) = 3493284e39a9d0ce3ade28201f54c32a
4
MD5 (main) = 82ae5011fe74d8612b996b2ba7ada13d
5
MD5 (main) = 938639953c59c99237110c606a543a50
6
MD5 (main) = 938639953c59c99237110c606a543a50
6
MD5 (main) = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
8
MD5 (main) = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
8
MD5 (main) = b88c362506aaaf6c6d74e3c734826734
10
```

I added `sleep 5s` before `make` and it still happens:

```
++ md5 main
+ echo MD5 '(main)' = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
MD5 (main) = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
+ ./main
8
+ rm main
+ for i in '$(seq 1 10)'
+ f 9
+ cmake . -DMY_MACRO=9
+ sleep 5s
+ make main
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
++ md5 main
+ echo MD5 '(main)' = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
MD5 (main) = b1dddef9f2aba5680213f3e7bdce276c
+ ./main
8
```

Update:
I use a different `make` from homebrew and the issue is gone. So it might be a MacOS `make` issue.

Comment: Passing a `-D` option to `cmake` is meaningful to `cmake`, but it does not translate into passing different options to the compiler. At least, not directly.

Comment: It is something about your project and using `MY_MACRO_USED_IN_CXX_CODE` in it. Without viewing the **code** (at least, `CMakeLists.txt`) it is impossible to help. Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry I'm being vague here. I use `target_compile_definitions` to pass them to the compiler. And during each pass I can see changes in `CMakeFiles/my_target.dir/flags.make` by print its md5. But *sometimes* the final executable doesn't change.

Comment: When I run that on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL2), `./main` outputs strictly **sequential** numbers. It looks like that in your case `make` sometimes doesn't recompile the program even after compilation flags are changed by CMake. You may find that by removing `&> /dev/null` from the `make` command line. Note, that compilation results in `.o` file, so removing `./main` (executable) doesn't enforce recompilation. You may remove `.o` file for truly force recompilation, but normally `make` should do that by itself...

Comment: Which **filesystem** (ext4, ..) you use for your tests? Probably, you work on a filesystem which has low **granularity** for modification timestamps. Note, that exactly modification timestamp is checked by `make` when it decides whether a file should be rebuilt from the sources or not.

Comment: I'm on MacOS so I guess it's APFS... Thanks for the hint I'll look into it

Comment: I suspected timestamps as well. But I added `sleep 5s` before `make` and the problem can still occur. See updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with timestamps. `sleep` should be inserted either before the call to `cmake` or after the call to `make` to avoid the timestamp problem (By lengthening the time gap between the most recent output of `cmake` and that of the target).

The GNU-make that comes with MacOS developer tools is from 2006. The latest version of GNU-make doesn't have this problem.